# Send Text Messages from Apex(Salesforce) without using app exchange products

Tags: apex, sms

I am trying to send text messages from Salesforce without using app exchange products. Can someone suggest some 3rd parties to send SMS messages?

Can anyone tell me the process of sending text messages from SF.

Answer (score 2):

Companies such as Twilio have [RESTful APIs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api) you can call from Apex to send SMSs. The calling code is simple enough e.g.:

```
private static HttpResponse twilioSend(SharedSmsSettings__c settings, Message m) {

    String endpoint = 'https://api.twilio.com';
    String version = '2010-04-01';

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

    req.setHeader('X-Twilio-Client', 'salesforce-' + version);
    req.setHeader('User-Agent', 'twilio-salesforce-' + endpoint);
    req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '+ EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(settings.TwilioAccountSid__c + ':' + settings.TwilioAuthToken__c)));

    req.setEndpoint(endpoint + '/' + version + '/Accounts/' + settings.TwilioAccountSid__c + '/Messages.json');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(''
           + 'From=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(settings.TwilioFromNumber__c, 'UTF-8')
           + '&To=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(m.phone, 'UTF-8')
           + '&Body=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(m.text, 'UTF-8')
           );

    return new Http().send(req);
}
```

but you must have an account with the supplier and inject those values into the request so there are quite a few settings needed.

Note that the above code is quite old: Twilio or other companies may well offer better mechanisms today e.g. bulk sends.